# Android Leaderboard Playstore Game Services

Tags: android, google-play, leaderboard

Is it somehow possible to set the public leaderboard to be the default one.
I am talking about the option when you show your leaderboard where is like

**Social - All**

[image: Android Leaderboard]

I cannot find any option in Playstore's Game Services.

Answer (score 1):

At this stage the API getLeaderboardIntent() does not allow you to set the filter for the leaderboard at launch. It is probably a workflow that is enforced by Google to promote adding friends to your G+ circles, but it makes for a really crappy experience when the player is the entry in their social leaderboard.

Hopefully this is made more flexible in a future update to play services.

Comment: Exactly my point, and I am sure that you are right about "sharing and adding friends to your G+", but still, the ordinary users got no idea about the Social-All switch..